# Always Encrypted - certificate cannot be used as a column master key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, certificate, windows-server, always-encrypted

I want to create a new column master key using certificate created in advanced. I use the following command to create a certificate in the `Windows Certificate Store - Local Machine`.

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -DnsName TEST_CERT_01
```

The issue is that when I try to select this certificate, I get the following error:

[image]

Can anyone tell what's wrong with the certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to **Create a self-signed certificate using PowerShell** section of [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/create-and-store-column-master-keys-always-encrypted).

To be used as Always encrypted CMKs, certificates require a specific configuration.

You should be able to create a certificate to be used as CMK using the following commands

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate is a Windows PowerShell cmdlet that creates a self-signed certificate. The below examples show how to generate a certificate that can be used as a column master key for Always Encrypted.
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "AlwaysEncryptedCert" -CertStoreLocation Cert:CurrentUserMy -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -Type DocumentEncryptionCert -KeyUsage KeyEncipherment -KeySpec KeyExchange -KeyLength 2048 

# To create a certificate in the local machine certificate store location you need to run the cmdlet as an administrator.
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "AlwaysEncryptedCert" -CertStoreLocation Cert:LocalMachineMy -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -Type DocumentEncryptionCert -KeyUsage KeyEncipherment -KeySpec KeyExchange -KeyLength 2048
```

This should work with Server 2012, you will have to install makecert utility if it does not exist:

```
makecert.exe -n "CN=Always Encrypted Certificate - exported" -pe -sr CurrentUser -r -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.8.2.2,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.11 -ss my -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider" -sy 1 -len 2048 -a sha256
```